# Copying a strstr search in a string to the string itself

Tags: c, string, strstr

I'm trying to parse a web page and extract weather info from it with C (masochist, I know).

Among other things in that page, there are these lines:

```
           <dt>Chance of <span class='wx-firstletter'>rain</span>:</dt>

                    <dt>Wind:</dt>

        <dt>Humidity:</dt>

        <dt>UV Index:</dt>

<dt>Snowfall:</dt>

        <dt>Sunrise:</dt>

        <dt>Moonrise:</dt>

        <dt>Moonphase:</dt>

                    <dt>Past 24-hr Precip:</dt>

        <dt>Past 24-hr Snow:</dt>

           <dt>Chance of <span class='wx-firstletter'>rain</span>:</dt>

                    <dt>Wind:</dt>

        <dt>Humidity:</dt>

        <dt>UV Index:</dt>

<dt>Snowfall:</dt>

        <dt>Sunset:</dt>

        <dt>Moonset:</dt>

        <dt>Moonphase:</dt>

                    <dt>Past 24-hr Precip:</dt>

        <dt>Past 24-hr Snow:</dt>
```

After I've downloaded the page, saved it in a file and read it with in an array with fread, I use a loop to read the array line by line, saving it to a temporary array (tmp).
The part that handles the lines containing the string < dt > is the following.

```
   } else if (strstr(tmp,"<dt>")) {
       strcpy(tmp,strstr(tmp,"<dt>")+4);
       strcpy(strstr(tmp,"</dt>")," \0");
       if (strstr(tmp,"Chance of"))
               strcpy(tmp,"Chance of precipitation: ");
       fwrite(tmp,1,strlen(tmp),file_tod);
   } else if ....
```

Everything goes well, apart from the Moonphase and Past 24h snow lines.

```
Chance of precipitation: 
Wind: 
Humidity: 
UV Index: 
Snowfall: 
Sunrise: 
Moonrise: 
Mo>
phase: 
Past 24-hr Precip: 
Paw: 24-hr Snow: 
Chance of precipitation: 
Wind: 
Humidity: 
UV Index: 
Snowfall: 
Sunset: 
Moonset: 
Mo>
phase: 
Past 24-hr Precip: 
Paw: 24-hr Snow:
```

Instead of getting Moonphase:, I get Mo>\nphase: and instead of getting Past 24h-Snow:, I get Paw: 24-hr Snow:.
The strange thing is that is happening with only these particular strings.
Can't I copy the result of strstr on a string to the string itself?

strcpy(tmp,strstr(tmp,"")+4);

Is this the offending line? I use the same method all over the rest of the code without problems.
If I use an intermediate variable (buff) to store the result of the strstr search

```
} else if (strstr(tmp,"<dt>")) {
    strcpy(buff,strstr(tmp,"<dt>")+4);
    strcpy(strstr(buff,"</dt>")," \0");
    if (strstr(buff,"Chance of"))
            strcpy(buff,"Chance of precipitation: ");
    fwrite(tmp,1,strlen(buff),file_tod);
} else if ....
```

everything's ok.

Thanks for any answer and sorry if it is very obvious.

EDIT: Came up with this

```
   } else if (strstr(tmp,"<dt>")) {
       memmove(tmp,strstr(tmp,"<dt>")+4,strlen(tmp)-(strlen(strstr(tmp,"<dt>")+4)));
       *(strstr(tmp,":")+1)=' ';
       *(strstr(tmp,":")+2)='\0';
       if (strstr(tmp,"Chance of"))
               strcpy(tmp,"Chance of precipitation: ");
       fwrite(tmp,1,strlen(tmp),file_tod);
```

Is it legit?

Answer (score 2):

The behaviour of functions like `strcpy()` when the source and target strings overlap is undefined.

If you must do the memory (string) move in situ, make sure you know the length of the string and use `memmove()`; that is guaranteed to work when the strings overlap.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the swift answer. I'll investigate into memmove and post back.